# How to accessing any variable name according to looping index in C

Tags: c, loops, variables

I have integer variables, I named them with n0 to n9, and i want to access them using loop, i try write this code to do that:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if(digit == 1){
        n[i] = n[i] + 1;
    }               
}
```

I know it's not true, but I don't know how to do it right. please guys help me. thanks.

Comment: what do you mean 'I named them' what C-instruction did you use for 'naming them n0 ...' ?

Comment: what is digit? what is n? if they are properly defined this code looks fine.

Comment: You either have all 10 in an *array* named `n` or you are not going to be looping...

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to understand what you are asking, but the answer is largely the same anyway. If you want to hold values for `n[0]` to `n[9]` in a data structure so you can loop though the values, then the immediate choice is an `array` (you can use a linked-list, tree, etc.., but I don't think you want those). The array provides the benefit of placing all values in a sequential block of memory. This allows you to iterate (loop) over the values in several ways. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 10

void prnarray (int *a, int n);

int main (void) {

    int i = 0;
    int n[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    printf ("array before loop:\n\n");
    prnarray (n, MAX);

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        if (n[i] == 1)
            n[i] += 1;

    printf ("\narray after loop:\n\n");
    prnarray (n, MAX);

    return 0;
}

void prnarray (int *a, int n)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf (" array[%2d] : %d\n", i, a[i]);
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/array09
array before loop:

 array[ 0] : 0
 array[ 1] : 1
 array[ 2] : 2
 array[ 3] : 3
 array[ 4] : 4
 array[ 5] : 5
 array[ 6] : 6
 array[ 7] : 7
 array[ 8] : 8
 array[ 9] : 9

array after loop:

 array[ 0] : 0
 array[ 1] : 2
 array[ 2] : 2
 array[ 3] : 3
 array[ 4] : 4
 array[ 5] : 5
 array[ 6] : 6
 array[ 7] : 7
 array[ 8] : 8
 array[ 9] : 9
```

On the other hand, if you have simply assigned your values to individual variables `n0, n1, n2, ...`, then your only option is to use some type of `list` or `tree` construct to provide an association between the individual variables (memory locations). Given your question, that seems well beyond the scope of what you are asking. Suffice it to say, if you have done this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 10

int main (void) {

    int i = 0;
    int n0 = 0;
    int n1 = 1;
    int n2 = 2;
    int n3 = 3;
    int n4 = 4;
    int n5 = 5;
    int n6 = 6;
    int n7 = 7;
    int n8 = 8;
    int n9 = 9;

    /* you are stuck - no way to loop,
       no guarantee n0 - n9 are contiguous
       in memory. (advanced datastruct needed)
    */

    return 0;
}
```

**start over...**